# C# Masked TextBox with 0 or decimals

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

Users have a textbox where they have to either enter a 0 or a value from 0.0001 to 0.9999.
What regex can I use here?  I have looked at other examples but don't see anything like this one.

Comment: Given your title your question doesn't make sense. Do you mean, what do you use for a mask?

Comment: Yes. What can I use for the mask.

Comment: Does `0.####` do what you want?

Comment: My bad and apologies. I did not realize a regular expression could be used as a mask.

Comment: Are you talking about using a masked text box control, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, or using a regular expression to validate input that has been entered into a control?  Desktop or web?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is quite an effective solution. It allows for any strings entered that is either just a '0' or strings with '0.' followed by up to 4 of any digit.

```
        Regex myRegex = new Regex("^(?:(?:0)|(?:0.[0-9]{1,4}))$");
        Console.WriteLine("Regex: " + myRegex + "\n\nEnter test input.");
        while (true)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (myRegex.IsMatch(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input + " is a match.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input + " isn't a match.");
            }
        }
```

Here's a list of tests...

[image]

Comment: thanks.  I am just now starting to try some of these.  I was able to compile this code but when i ran it and the textbox loads , I got an error saying "Invalid synax". I am probably doing something wrong.  In the textbox I tried "regular" and "regex":  I hve this one line of code:   this.Mytextbox.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "^(?:(?:0)|(?:0.[0-9]{1,4}))$";

Comment: You will want to add this code to the usings at the top of your code.`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Chris, if you consider my answer to have helped best, could you please mark it as _the_ answer so as to close this question with resolve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/(0)+(.)+([0-9])/g
```

Also see thing link that might helps you build you won expreession.
http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will do the work but I was not tested for all cases.

```
Regex _regex = new Regex("^[0]+(.[0-9]{1,4})?$");
if (input == "0" || _regex.IsMatch(input))
{
     //Match
}
else
{
     //Does not match
}
```

Note: input is a string, in your case Textbox.Text!

Answer (score 0):

This is ready to use `KeyPress` event handler of `TextBox` control. It will prevent any input, except numeric between 0.0001 and 0.9999:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Only one dot is possible
        if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Contains('.') && (e.KeyChar == '.')) e.Handled = true;

        //Only numeric keys are acceptable
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.')) e.Handled = true;

        //Only one zero in front is acceptable, next has to be dot
        if (((sender as TextBox).Text == "0") && (e.KeyChar == '0')) e.Handled = true;

        double value = 0;
        string inputValue = (sender as TextBox).Text + e.KeyChar;

        if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 0)
        {
            //Just in case parse input text into double
            if (double.TryParse(inputValue, out value))
            {
                //Check if value is between 0.0001 and 0.9999
                if (value > 0.9999) e.Handled = true;
                if (((sender as TextBox).Text.Length > 4) && (value < 0.0001)) e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar != '0')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```